# Singular Value Decomposition Theorem: Corollary

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, svd

In a linear algebra and analysis course [it's a hybrid course between the two], we recently had the SVD (singular value decomposition) theorem, and the prof. told us (due to lack of time without proof):

**Corollary 2.39**: Let $A = U\Sigma V^{T}$ be the singular value decomposition of $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$, where the singular values $\sigma_1 \geq \dots \geq \sigma_p \geq 0$, where $p = \min\left\{ m, n\right\}$. Further, for $k<p$, define

$$A_{k} = U\Sigma_{k}V^{T},$$

where $$\Sigma_{k} = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_1 \qquad\qquad\qquad 0 \\ \qquad \ddots \qquad \\ \quad\quad\quad\sigma_{k}  \\ 0 \qquad\qquad\qquad 0  \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{m\times n},$$

with $k < p$. It holds that: $$A_k = \arg\min_{\text{rank}\left( B \right) = k}\left|\left| A - B\right|\right|_{2} = \arg\min_{\text{rank}\left( B\right) = k}\left|\left| A - B\right|\right|_{F}.$$

---

Upon question on a hint of the proof the lecturer said that one might want to use the following relations: $$\text{Tr}\left( AB^{T} \right) \leq \sum_{j=1}^{p} \sigma_{j}\gamma_{j},$$ where $\gamma_{1} \geq \dots \geq \gamma_{p} \geq 0$ denote the singular values of $B\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$. I also proved the following two relations:

$$\left|\left| A - A_{k} \right|\right|_{2} = \sigma_{k+1}, \qquad \left|\left| A - A_{k} \right|\right|_{F} = \left( \sum_{j = k+1}^{p} \sigma_{j}^{2} \right)^{1/2} \qquad $$

---

**IDEA**: I tried several things, one of them being: $$\left|\left| A - B\right|\right|_{2} \leq \left|\left| A - A_{k} \right|\right|_{2} + \left|\left| B - A_{k} \right|\right|_{2} = \sigma_{k+1} + \left|\left| B - A_{k} \right|\right|_{2}$$

But then, I am not sure how to continue. We already know from the Corollary that $A_k = U\Sigma_k V^{T}$ [by definition], and $B = \tilde{U}\tilde{\Sigma}\tilde{V^{T}}$ [by the SVD Theorem], *i.e.*
$\left|\left| B - A_{k} \right|\right|_{2} = \left|\left| \tilde{U}\tilde{\Sigma}\tilde{V^{T}} -  U\Sigma_k V^{T}\right|\right|_{2}$.

Could anybody help out, please, on how to continue?

Comment: In the statement of the corollary, shouldn't the two argmins have different values? The first should be $\sigma_{k+1}$ (as you showed) and the second should be as is. And your $\|A-A_k\|_F$ ought to match the quantity in the corollary (you have $\sigma_j$ instead of $\sigma_j^2$ inside the some for some reason).

Comment: Thanks for the careful reading, you're right! Please feel free to add a quick answer or a short comment, I'm really curious why this corollary holds..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operator norm:

You've shown $\|A-A_k\|_2 = \sigma_{k+1}$, so it remains to show that $\|A-B\|_2 \ge \sigma_{k+1}$ for any rank $k$ matrix $B$.

- Suppose $B$ has rank $k$. The nullspace of $B$ has dimension $n-k$.
- Let $v_1, \ldots, v_{k+1}$ be the top singular vectors of $A$ (i.e. $Av_i = \sigma_i u_i$). The span of these vectors has dimension $k+1$.
- Since the above two subspaces have dimensions $n-k$ and $k+1$ summing to more than $n$, its intersection is nonempty. Let $z$ be a unit vector in both these subspaces.
- Show that
  $$\|A-B\|_2^2 \ge \|(A-B)z\|_2^2 = \|Az\|_2^2 \ge \sigma_{k+1}^2.$$
  (The first inequality is due to the definition of the operator norm. The second equality is due to $z \in \ker B$. The third inequality can be shown by writing $z$ as a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_{k+1}$ and noting that these vectors map to $\sigma_i u_i$ for $i \ge k+1$.)

---

Frobenius norm:

You've shown $\|A-A_k\|_F^2 = \sum_{j=k+1}^p \sigma_j^2$ (note that you still have a typo), so it remains to show that $\|A-B\|_F^2 \ge  \sum_{j=k+1}^p \sigma_j^2$ for any rank $k$ matrix $B$.

For a matrix $M$ I will use $\sigma_i(M)$ to denote the $i$th singular value of $M$, and let $M_k$ denote the result of keeping only the top $k$ singular values (just as you have defined $A_k$).

Using the result $\|M - M_k\| = \sigma_{k+1}$ that you proved,
\begin{align}
\sigma_i(A-B)
&= \|(A-B) - (A-B)_{i-1}\|_2
\\
&=  \|A - (B +  (A-B)_{i-1})\|_2
\\
&\ge \|A - A_{k+i-1}\|_2
\\
&= \sigma_{k+i}(A).
\end{align}
The inequality is due to $\text{rank}(B + (A-B)_{i-1}) \le \text{rank}(B) + \text{rank}((A-B)_{i-1}) = k+i-1$, combined with the above result that $A_{k+i-1}$ is the best rank $k+i-1$ approximation of $A$ in the operator norm.

Using the fact that the squared Frobenius norm is the sum of squares of its singular values, we have
$$\|A-B\|_F^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{\min(m,n)} (\sigma_i(A-B))^2
\ge\sum_{j=k+1}^p (\sigma_j(A))^2.$$

Comment: I would have two immediate follow-up questions on this: (i) What are the $u_{i}$? (ii) Why does $Av_{i} = \sigma_{i} u_{i}$ hold?

Comment: @hermione-granger Sorry, $u_i$ are the columns of $U$ in the SVD $A=U\Sigma V^\top$.

Comment: No problem! But could you please explain then why $Av_{i} = U\Sigma V^{T} v_{i} \overset{!}{=} \sigma_{i}u_{i}$ hold? For example, we don't even know how to evaluate $V^{T}v_{i}$, do we?

Comment: @hermione-granger $v_i$ is the $i$th column of $V$, so $V^\top v_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector (all zeros except for a $1$ in the $i$th component) because the columns of $V$ are orthonormal. This is an important characterization of the right- and left-singular vectors and singular values of $A$.

Comment: Okay, just to make sure: You mean that *in general*, the singular values of $A$ are just the columns of $V^{T}$ with our chosen notation? We probably had that, then, but I couldn't find it in my notes, probably overlooked it.. Could you please send a link for a proof or so? :)

Comment: @hermione-granger Singular values $\sigma_i$ are real numbers, not vectors. The columns of $V$ are known as the [right] singular vectors, and the columns of $U$ are the [left] singular vectors. You can directly show $Av_i=\sigma_i u_i$ by performing the matrix multiplication directly and using the fact that the columns of $V$ are orthonormal as I mentioned in my previous comment. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Singular_values,_singular_vectors,_and_their_relation_to_the_SVD) for references.

Comment: Okay. :) Also: You consider in your proof two subspaces, namely $\text{ker}(B)$, the nullspace or kernel of $B$, and $\text{span}\{v_{1}, \dots, v_{k+1}\}$. Whereas the first is a subspace of the vector space $B$, isn't the second a subspace of $\subseteq A$? Because then I am not sure whether your next statement holds? Because I know the following formula, where I denote $\langle.,.\rangle$ for the span of two subspaces:

$\text{dim}(\langle U_1, U_2\rangle) = \text{dim}(U_1) + \text{dim}(U_2) - \text{dim}(U_1 \cap U_2)$.

Comment: @hermione-granger Both are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. And yes the formula you mentioned is how to arrive at the next statement.

Comment: Concerning the operator norm: I think I understand the proof now, but how do we go from $||A - B||_{2} \leq || A - A_{k}||_{2} + ||B - A_{k}||_{2} = \sigma_{k+1} + ||B-A_{k}||_{2}$ and $|| A - B||_{2} \geq \sigma_{k+1}$ to the statement that we want to prove?

Comment: @hermione-granger The proof that I wrote down does not apply the triangle inequality. The inequality $\|A-B\| \ge \sigma_{k+1}$ alone proves $\min_{B : \text{rank}(B)=k} \|A-B\| \ge \sigma_{k+1}$. To show equality, take $B=A_k$.